# PHP echo button with on-click wont function well

Tags: php, html

I have tried to echo the button, however the link just does not work, so I thinks something is wrong with the href link, please help.

```
echo "<input class='button_normal' type='button' value='entertainment' onclick='window.location..href=<Electronic and Entertainment Products.php>'>";
```

Comment: 2 dots in `location..href`

Comment: plus .`..href=<E...`? no quotes on the href, and `<>` on a url is just... wrong.

Comment: ^ that will cause a parse error.

Comment: could you please advise or rewrite the code.

Comment: do you have a php file with name like this  "Electronic and Entertainment Products.php" !!

Comment: yhes i do have php with this name.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code and look at your HTML source.

Comment: their are no errors with the code however it just does not run.

Comment: this code works. 
 echo '<span class="Entertainment"><a href="Electronic and Entertainment Products.php">products</a></span>'; however it shows the button not like I wanted it to look like.

Comment: `<a href` and input are two different animals altogether. The answer given below by Polaris works. Whatever you're not showing us; show it. Plus, make sure you did in fact remove the extra dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@james_91 The code below should do the trick:

```
<?php
echo "<input class=\"button_normal\" type=\"button\" value=\"entertainment\" onclick=\"window.location.href='Electronic and Entertainment Products.php'\">";
?>
```

I would advise against using spaces in your file names so use underscores instead maybe.

JS within a button within PHP works best with escaped quotation marks, you also had two dots in between location and href as commented by Fred -ii-

Comment: this code does not work as it shows the button as textbox.

Comment: @james_91 Works fine for me, you must have a conflicting open tag somewhere, copy and paste the code into a blank php file.

Comment: Hi, thank the code works.